# How to change Wifi P2P device name?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to detect and connect two Android mobiles using Wifi P2P method and I have been successful in it. But, I want a different name to be shown on the other device when it discovers mine.

Since, I am using Samsung J7 Prime 2(Android 9), changing Device name or Bluetooth name changes the Wifi P2p name, but the code for that didn't work. I tried the same code on Android 6.0.1 i.e. API 23 and it worked fine.

```java
swtWifi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                changeDevName("Tony Stark");

            }
});

public void changeDevName(String devNewName) {
        try {
            Method method = manager.getClass().getMethod("setDeviceName", WifiP2pManager.Channel.class, String.class, WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class);

            method.invoke(manager, channel, devNewName, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name successfully changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Request failed: " + reason, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is happening when your code does not work? Any exception? Error messages?

Comment: @SolutionMill The app neither crashes nor does it show any error. The name of the device doesn't change.